# Centering an Activityindicator on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the XAML above code and I am trying to put an ActivityIndicator on the center of the page after click the Button. I tried using examples of the web, but not succesful.

```cs
<ScrollView>
  <StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Padding="30" Spacing="2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <Label x:Name="lblUsuario" Text="ID do Usuário" TextColor="#555" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
      <Entry x:Name="EntUsuario" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Digite usuário" PlaceholderColor="#CCC" FontSize="20" TextColor="#555" />
      <Label x:Name="lblSenha" Text="Senha de acesso" TextColor="#555" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
      <Entry x:Name="EntSenha" Placeholder="Digite sua senha" Keyboard="Default" IsPassword="True" FontSize="20" PlaceholderColor="#CCC" TextColor="#555" />   
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Padding="30" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">  
      <Button x:Name="BtnLogin" Text="Login" BorderColor="#CB9600" BackgroundColor="#F4B400" />
    </StackLayout> 
  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the beggining of the code:

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            InitializeComponent();

            int contadorErroLogin = 0;
            string result = null;

            BtnLogin.Clicked += async (sender, e) =>
                {
                    IsBusy = true;
```

When starts IsBusy = false but the screen seems like were true .

Comment: Using Grid which include the scrollview and activityindicator

Comment: what does it means to center an element in a ScrollView ?

Comment: For those who came here looking for a single page with a centered indicator: `<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"><ActivityIndicator IsRunning="true"/></AbsoluteLayout>`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using this :

```
<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">

       <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
           <ScrollView>
              <StackLayout>
                  <StackLayout Padding="30" Spacing="2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Label x:Name="lblUsuario" Text="ID do Usuário" TextColor="#555" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Entry x:Name="EntUsuario" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Digite usuário" PlaceholderColor="#CCC" FontSize="20" TextColor="#555" />
                    <Label x:Name="lblSenha" Text="Senha de acesso" TextColor="#555" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Entry x:Name="EntSenha" Placeholder="Digite sua senha" Keyboard="Default" IsPassword="True" FontSize="20" PlaceholderColor="#CCC" TextColor="#555" />   
               </StackLayout>
               <StackLayout Padding="30" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">  
                    <Button x:Name="BtnLogin" Text="Login" BorderColor="#CB9600" BackgroundColor="#F4B400" />
               </StackLayout> 
             </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>

        </StackLayout>

       <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" Padding="12"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1">

       <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Color ="#80000000"/>

       <Label Text="Loading..." HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>

        </StackLayout>

 </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: strange!! I tryed this and i puted IsBusy=false when starts and true when clicked...But i Always have the ActivityIndicator running in front of.

Comment: You need to set it false again after the button click. Is there any asynchronous operation being performed on button click ?

Comment: I did it... when open the screen, the activity is on...without click at the button

Comment: can you post the logic of click event, what exactly happening because it works perfectly in my app.

Comment: I tried to comment the label. At this case, the circle of ActivityIndicator are not visible... i also changed the color

Comment: While indicator is visible, how to block the user from clicking on controls defined inside a form?

Comment: @ThamaraiT Disable your content page while activity indicator is visible

Comment: @ Himanshu Dwivedi By the property 'IsEnabled' right?

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This code was very useful in me overlaying a Marker over my Xamarin.Forms Map which acted as a Centred Marker.

Comment: @MomoduDeenSwarray Please upvote if this helps.

Answer (score 13):

You can try to encapsulate the your `ScrollViewer` inside a `Grid` and under your `ScrollViewer` insert an ÀctivityIndicator` centered vertically and horizontally.

Like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollView>
      <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="30" Spacing="2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Label x:Name="lblUsuario" Text="ID do Usuário" TextColor="#555" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
          <Entry x:Name="EntUsuario" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Digite usuário" PlaceholderColor="#CCC" FontSize="20" TextColor="#555" />
          <Label x:Name="lblSenha" Text="Senha de acesso" TextColor="#555" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
          <Entry x:Name="EntSenha" Placeholder="Digite sua senha" Keyboard="Default" IsPassword="True" FontSize="20" PlaceholderColor="#CCC" TextColor="#555" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="30" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Button x:Name="BtnLogin" Text="Login" BorderColor="#CB9600" BackgroundColor="#F4B400" />
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" IsRunning="False" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
  </Grid>
```

And the code behind this view:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.BtnLogin.Clicked += BtnLogin_Clicked;
}

private void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
    // TODO: do stuff here
}
```

When I click on the `BtnLogin` I say that the activityIndicator should run.

What happen in the grid is that all controls within the grid take the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` 0 by default. So all controls are the one on the other.

**EDIT:**

If you trying to have a MVVM approach, you can define your current view has `BindingContext`

View:

```
  <Grid>
    <ScrollView>
      <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="30" Spacing="2" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Label x:Name="lblUsuario" Text="ID do Usuário" TextColor="#555" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
          <Entry x:Name="EntUsuario" Keyboard="Numeric" Placeholder="Digite usuário" PlaceholderColor="#CCC" FontSize="20" TextColor="#555" />
          <Label x:Name="lblSenha" Text="Senha de acesso" TextColor="#555" FontSize="20" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
          <Entry x:Name="EntSenha" Placeholder="Digite sua senha" Keyboard="Default" IsPassword="True" FontSize="20" PlaceholderColor="#CCC" TextColor="#555" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="30" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Button x:Name="BtnLogin" Text="Login" BorderColor="#CB9600" BackgroundColor="#F4B400" />
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!-- The '{Binding IsBusy}' is going to search the 'IsBusy' property inside the 'BindingContext'. In our case, is the code behind -->
    <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
  </Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // Define the binding context
        this.BindingContext = this;

        // Set the IsBusy property
        this.IsBusy = false;

        // Login button action
        this.BtnLogin.Clicked += BtnLogin_Clicked;
    }

    private void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.IsBusy = true;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your page's xaml add an activity indicator form component like below

```
<ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityMonitor" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" 
   VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Color="Red" />
```

In your xaml code behind.  In your page's contructor add the following:

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //This will initialize your activity inidicator and set busy to false
        this.activityMonitor.BindingContext = this;
        this.IsBusy = false;
    }
...
}
```

Now in your method:
example:

```
public void Login_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.IsBusy = true;
    //Login logic. //call web service
    //Finished processing.  Set isBusy to false;

    this.IsBusy = false;
}
```